# search for phrase in line of text box vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET and I've got a text box which contains the following information (that changes depending on the video file selected in a list box):-

```
type: ffmpeg-producer
filename: C:\caspar\Server\media\\adi.divx
width: 640
height: 360
progressive: false
fps: 25
loop: false
frame-number: 0
nb-frames: 4626
file-frame-number: 0
file-nb-frames: 4626
```

When I click a button, I need to add the data to a variable. So for example, I would need to take 4626 from the line

> nb-frames: 4626

and 25 from the

> line fps:25

and put them both in variables to then calculate the actual duration.

Comment: I'm curious where you get that information before putting it in the textbox.

Comment: @the_lotus it looks like stdout captured from something (maybe ffmpeg encoding).  The duration etc could be gotten using MediaProps

Comment: the info is from the lib file used to communicate with Caspar CG. I'll give Media Props a look though, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal varName As String) As String
    Dim lines() As String = Split(TextBox1.Text, Delimiter:=Environment.NewLine)
    For Each line As String In lines
        Dim words() As String = Split(line, Delimiter:=": ", Limit:=2)
        If words(0) = varName And words.Length = 2 Then
            Return words(1)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression approach. If you you are not familiar with regular expressions I strongly encourage you to into it.

Here is what you would do (where txtMyTextbbox is the textbox, that holds your data:

```
Dim strRegex as String = "([\w-]*):\s*(.*)"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
Dim strTargetString As String = txtMyTextbox.Text

For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
     If myMatch.Success Then
    dim category = myMatch.Groups(1).Value
    dim value = myMatch.Groups(2).Value
  End If
Next
```

This code loops through all matches in your textbox text and looks for a text followed by a colon followed by spaces and the rest of the line. Each match is captured in the myMatch variable where you can access the part before the colon through myMatch.Groups(1).value and the part after the colon (excluding the space) through the second group.

Leave a comment if you have further questions.